# In firestore, how to search for a field containing similar text

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

In firestore database, there is a field for location, such as :

```
{
...
"location" : "London, England",
...
}
```

I want to get this for the search term : **London/ london/ England/ england**

So far I've tried this :

```
              Firestore.instance
              .collectionGroup("posts")
              .orderBy(location)
              .where(location,
                  isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: widget.location)
              .where(location,
                  isLessThanOrEqualTo: widget.location + "z")
```

How to solve this?

Comment: if I understand well, are you trying to implement a no lower/upper case sensitive search?

Comment: You will need to store two versions of your data; a lower cased version and then a displayed version. Perform queries on the lower cased version and use the displayed version for the UI.

Comment: Yes, no case sensitive search. For the given example, I want to get the data for the terms "london" or "England" or "London" or "england".

Comment: Yes? Meaning the issue is resolved?